# React router history push goes to initial route

Tags: react-router-dom

I have the routing configuration like below in App.tsx

```html
<BrowserRouter>
  <Navbar />
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/layout" component={Layout} />
      <Layout />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In the Layout component routing is like below

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/layout/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/layout/authordocument/:id/edit" component={Editor} />
    <Route path="/layout/authordocument/:id" component={DocumentView} />
    <Route path="/layout/authordocument" component={AuthorDocument} />
    <Route path="/layout/managetemplate/:id" component={TemplateView} />
    <Route path="/layout/managetemplate" component={ManageTemplates} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

if i try to visit the path `/layout/authordocument/:id/edit` by pasting the URL in the browser it works fine

But If i am already in the path `/layout/authordocument/:id` and then try to navigate via code through `Link` or `history.push` to `/layout/authordocument/:id/edit` then it is going to `path="/"` for some reasons which is the component `Home`.

Any idea here what could be possibly wrong ?

I am using `import { useHistory, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'` to navigate between the components.